# Django translate cached file in Chrome never change

Tags: django, google-chrome

I use Django built-in translation, but in Chrome, the updated po and mo files are not recognised, even I delete both of them and re-generate again. For the development server in Chrome, it just shows some old translation files. Even I deleted all the cached files in Chrome, the problem is the same.

I just wonder how the mo and po files are used by Django and navigator. And do I have a way to debug what context has actually been sent to the template?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it is not a chrome issue. Also, it is nothing to do with context. Django's development server (and django system in general) load .mo files in memory when it starts. So editing .po and re-generating .mo files requires restart of your application.

> And do I have a way to debug what context has actually been sent to
>   the template?

Here is a great tool for that called [debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: It is strange that my Chrome and Safari show different content, even if I deleted both mo and po files and restart the dev server, Chrome still has loaded translated files from somewhere unknown, while Safari shows default English language contents.

Comment: did you try to disable cache in chrome or something like that?

Comment: finally I solved it by adding LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py to explicitly declare the po file and comment out locale middleware. I tried to clear the cache in Chrome before, but wasn't successful.